# How many classes can see ResNet?

Tags: python, image, image-recognition, resnet

ResNet was trained on the "ImageNet 2012 classifi-cation dataset [35] that consists of 1000 classes" - Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition.

Okey, so after training we have one parameter which means how may channels we have=filters which describes features, eg. one filter can describe "is there face or not".

In the end, ResNet have 1000 classes, can recognize 1000 classes?

Fc in the model of ResNet architecture means features?

I am right?

[image]

Comment: fc layer will compute the class scores, resulting in volume of size [1x1x10], where each of the 10 numbers correspond to a class score, such as among the 10 categories of CIFAR-10. As with ordinary Neural Networks and as the name implies, each neuron in this layer will be connected to all the numbers in the previous volume

Comment: "how may channels" = "how many channels"?

Comment: FC = Fully Connected. This is used to describe the connection between 2 layers, namely that each neuron from one connect to all the neurons of the other. Also, yes ResNet can classify 1000 classes from the ImageNet dataset. Depending on the model type, you can also get pre-trained weights from Keras.